# How to pass overall data of one webpage to another in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, builder, resume

I am a newbie javascript developer. I made a Web-based Resume Builder. In which i have a login page and main form where user will enter his/her information in textboxes but i am struggling over how to pass the entire data from that page to Preview page in a proper resume pattern.

Or do you have any other sort of recommendations for this then hit me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use the database, you have to store the data from the form into an array or an object. and on the preview page, you can load the data from the array or object. Javascript treats the array and the object in the same way.